# FullCalendar eventReceive handler stays in memory somehow

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm loading HTML with jQuery `get()`, and creating a FullCalendar (v5.10.2) in the loaded content.

If I load this HTML content (with my FullCalendar being initialized) multiple times, `eventReceive` will also be called multiple times when I drop external events, as if the eventHandler for previous FullCalendar instances stays in memory despite the object being de-referenced.

So I've looked into `destroy()` and `delete` in an attempt to clear any old fullCalendar data. No errors when calling the commands, but still `eventReceive` is called multiple times. Also tried looking into `replace` which some recommend, but still no luck.

Despite manually calling `destroy()` on the active FullCalendar before loading a new one, `eventRecieve` from previous FullCalendar instances are still fired, it seems.
For some odd reason it only seems to apply to `eventReceive` though, and not other eventHandlers. It doesn't happen for `eventDrop` nor `eventResize` for example.

Anyone got any ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue for us to analyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was creating `new FullCalendar.Draggable()` every time I loaded the FullCalendar. I didn't realize that should only be done once, and that it would subsequently automatically convert new elements to draggables.